# ActiveSheet.CodeName does not work in protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works when I remove protection of the sheet (using the password) but does not work while the sheet is protected, hence I cannot share the file with others.

`Sheet1.Cells(LastRowDataBase + 1, "E") = ActiveSheet.CodeName`

Comment: You can `.Unprotect` -> run code -> `.Protect` with VBA

Comment: It's because the cell you're trying to write to is protected - if it was the same cell each time you could manually unlock it and protect the rest of the sheet.  In this case though I'd go with @DragonSamu comment and unlock the sheet, write the value and lock again.  So not really a case of `ActiveSheet.CodeName does not work` more a case of `can't write value to protected cell`.

Comment: Thanks guys, but it's not working. I have added `ThisWorkbook.Unprotect` at the start of the macro and then `ThisWorkbook.Protect` at the end.

Comment: @peetman did you do it as followed: `ThisWorkbook.Unprotect "ExamplePasword"` ?